# displaying different pages using scroll view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have to create a profile screen in order to display user profile image and below the screen there are 4 options given in order to show:

1. Profile
2. Gallery
3. Tattoos
4. Videos

I have used `UIImage` for displaying User's profile and a scrollview in which I have used 4 buttons to show the options.

What I am confused about now how to show all the four contents of those options by clicking the button?

Should I use container or normal view?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use segment control for same and you can change bottom view as per segment index selection.

Comment: You can user either view or segment controll

Comment: I think your best option is to go for a proper library. If not you can use a UISegmentedControl with different viewcontrollers.

Comment: Can we scroll in segment control from a page to another???

Answer (score 0):

What I would use here is a `UIPageViewController`.

It uses a scroll view to display its contents but it allows you to serve `UIViewControllers` as its pages.

You can then use a custom control, maybe a segmented control or something else, to allow the user to change which page is displayed.

The user will also be able to swipe between the pages.